# Karate : How add a header with cookie in my feature?

Tags: api, cookies, karate

I have a list of requests in Postman that I need to test with Karate. For each request I need to send a cookie to the API: "INGRESSCOOKIE = XXX; Path = / api; Secure; HttpOnly;".

I tried putting these values in '* header cookie' or 'Given cookie ...' but it doesn't work.

How should I do it ? All my requests work on Postman

Thanks !!

Comment: most likely you don't need to set cookies, read the linked answer and the docs. if still stuck, follow this process (or use postman ;) https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue